# How to remove Skip testcases from cypress runner

Tags: tags, cypress

Is it possible, to remove skipped testcases from cypress runner and cypress cucumber html report and not to show them

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to achieve with having skipped test not show up?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.